# Rough classification of segment metrics

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

For a dynamical project, I need to bound uniformly a quantity defined from a metric on the segment $I=[0,1]$ over *all* metrics inducing the usual topology. The details do not matter too much, I wonder whether any non-completely-trivial information is known about such metrics, whether there is some sort of rough classification. I moreover have some monotony property that may help.

So, given a topological space $X$, let $\mathcal{D}(X)$ be the set of all metrics $d:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}_+$ that moreover induce the topology of $X$. Let say that a subset $\mathcal{M}\subset \mathcal{D}(X)$ is *minorizing* if for all $d'\in\mathcal{D}(X)$, there exist some $d\in\mathcal{M}$ and some $C>0$ such that $d\le C d'$.

My question would be

> Can we describe some (all ?) inclusion-minimal minorizing subsets of $\mathcal{D}(I)$? Or at least, a small minorizing subset of $\mathcal{D}(I)$?

but I have honestly not yet given enough thought to it yet; my real question is rather whether any information on this sort of questions is already available in the literature. It is very difficult to find keywords that would extract relevant references without being flooded with automatic classification research.

**Edit:** to make things more precise (but I do not want to reduce the scope of relevant reference: any one remotely related to the question would be nice), let me give a more focused question:

> Is the set of metrics that are conjugate to the Euclidean metric by a homeomorphism minorizing?

Comment: What you call "minorizing" is known as "cofinal" (in a suitable ordering) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinal_(mathematics).

Comment: What I don't see right away is whether any two metrics have a lower bound... there's a lower bound among semi-metrics (it's the graph distance when one draws edges of both distances between any two points) but it's unclear to me that this does not glue two points at distance zero.

Comment: @YCor: very little is clear to me right now. Minimality is not so important, a more general notion of smallness is ok (e.g. a long list of nice properties one can have for all metrics in $\mathcal{M}$).

Comment: I thought a bit more: there are two metrics (each conjugate to the standard one by some homeomorphism) that have no common lower bound among metrics (i.e., their infimum among semimetrics is not a metric: actually it's zero). So your poset is not lower filtering.